# Is there a reason why I cannot await function on root level in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code produces SyntaxError:

```
async def some_func():
    print(45)

await some_func()
```

`SyntaxError: 'await' outside function`

Is the behavior intentional design or a result of implementation difficulties? Why it can't be interpreted as this:

```
async def some_func():
    print(45)

asyncio.run(some_func())
```

Comment: There are more async libraries than just asyncio.